# Two Rails projects on two different droplets with single domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, digital-ocean, puma

Is it possible to use one domain for two Rails projects on two different droplets?

I have two droplets (DigitaOcean) with two different Rails 5 projects (ubuntu 18, nginx, puma). One for the website and another for API (backend for mobile app).

I mean that I want to buy `example.com` domain. After that, I want to use `example.com` for website and `api.example.com` for API.

I think that I should make some work with nginx config? Should I use private IP? Which droplet should process traffic depending on url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to worry about nginx config, domain handling or smth else by the server. All you need to do in this case is create 2 droplets:
website droplet with IP 1
API droplet with IP2

then in your DNS manager (DigitalOcean or somewhere else where your nameservers are pointing) add A records:

**example.com**     to  IP1
(optional) www.example.com CNAME to example.com
**api.example.com** to IP2

No smart or complex configuration needed :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily add a sub domain, and point this subdomain to your droplet.
I am not too familiar with Digital Ocean, but it should be easy enough.
You just need to create a sub domain(process depends on domain provider), and simply point this to your droplet.